# Text-align text 45 degrees

Tags: css, css-shapes, text-align

[image: Screen]

I would like to achieve text-alignment effect like on the screen above.
Any suggestions?

Comment: That's not about text align, but a div with a png background. Anyway what have you tried yet? read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This should be closed as offtopic. Try something by yourself and ask a specific question with a specific problem

Comment: I have changed screen to be more specific

Comment: Read @MattiaNocerino comment, click on that link, and read!

Comment: *Any suggestions?* – Yes, have a look at [CSS-Shapes](http://webplatform.adobe.com/shapes/)

Answer (score 7):

I believe you are looking for the `shape-outside` property.

> The shape-outside CSS property uses shape values to define the float area for a float and will cause inline content to wrap around the shape instead of the float's bounding box.

This allows for values such as:

- circle(): for making circular shapes.
- ellipse(): for making elliptical shapes.
- inset(): for making rectangular shapes.
- polygon(): for creating any shape with more than 3 vertices.
- url(): identifies which image should be used to wrap text around.
- initial: the float area is unaffected.
- inherit: inherits shape-outside value from parent.

**However**, its [current support](http://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside) is **very weak**, with only really chrome supporting it.

For more information, please see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside)

---

**Small work around**

*Disclaimer* <sup>This should only be used for demo only and I do not recommend this approach in a production environment</sup>

you may be able to use nth-child *if* you knew how many lines this paragraph will be, but this presumes you'll be using a set width/etc:

```css
div {
  background: tomato;
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
}
div span {
  display: block;
}
div span:nth-child(1) {margin-left: 0px;}
div span:nth-child(2) {margin-left: 10px;}
div span:nth-child(3) {margin-left: 20px;}
div span:nth-child(4) {margin-left: 30px;}
div span:nth-child(5) {margin-left: 40px;}
div span:nth-child(6) {margin-left: 50px;}
div span:nth-child(7) {margin-left: 60px;}
div span:nth-child(8) {margin-left: 70px;}
div span:nth-child(9) {margin-left: 80px;}
div span:nth-child(10) {margin-left: 90px;}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Some nice long text</span>
  <span>Some nice long text</span>
  <span>Some nice long text</span>
  <span>Some nice long text</span>
  <span>Some nice long text</span>
  <span>Some nice long text</span>
  <span>Some nice long text</span>
  <span>Some nice long text</span>
  <span>Some nice long text</span>
  <span>Some nice long text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man:) That is what I was looking for. It's a pity that browser support is so weak:)

Comment: @ŁukaszRo If you are 100% set on doing this, you **may** be able to do something with `nth-child`, but IMO it's hackish.